dockerfile pip error cannot find versions for packages in requirements.txt
I have a dockerfile like this:
FROM nexus3/docker-hub/apache/airflow:slim-2.10.0-python3.11

ENV PIP_CONFIG_FILE=/home/airflow/pip.conf
ENV AIRFLOW_VERSION=2.10.0

RUN --mount=type=secret,id=pip,target=/home/airflow/pip.conf,uid=50000,required=true \
    --mount=type=bind,source=requirements.txt,target=requirements.txt \
    pip install --no-cache-dir "apache-airflow[celery,postgres,statsd]==${AIRFLOW_VERSION}" -r requirements.txt

I then build as such:
docker build -t nexus3.systems.uk.hsbc:18094/docker-hub/11976246/apache/airflow:slim-2.10.0-python3.11 --secret id=pip,src=pip.conf .

My requirements.txt file looks like this:
requests
httpx
psycopg2-binary
psycopg[binary,pool]
oracledb
pyxlsb
pandas
polars
statsd

I then get error:
1.769 Requirement already satisfied: requests in /home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 1)) (2.32.3)
1.769 Requirement already satisfied: httpx in /home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 2)) (0.27.0)
2.625 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement psycopg2-binary (from versions: none)
3.520 ERROR: No matching distribution found for psycopg2-binary

I'm not sure what is really going wrong here.

try with psycopg2.
